# Why do I get this error when using listings' Algol language, and how can I fix it?

Tags: errors, listings

Using the `listings` package, I am trying to extend an existing language definition (`Algol`) with an additional keyword. It seems to be working (I get a desired result), but it produces an error during compilation:

```
! Package keyval Error: keywordcomment undefined.
```

I am not using comments in the code - I don't need them. How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=ALGOL,morekeywords={ID}]
... some code ...
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @CygnusX1 Ask the moderators for joining the accounts.

Comment: @CygnusX1 Looks like a bug to me. You should notify the author.

Comment: @CygnusX1 The error arises even without `morekeywords`

Comment: The error occurs just with the one option `language=ALGOL`, so definitely looks like a bug that should be reported.

Comment: @CygnusX1 Please use http://tex.stackexchange.com/contact to request an account merge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does look like a bug. I haven't completely isolated it (yet!), but it seems to stem from a failure of the `listings` package to properly load the "aspect" `keywordcomments` (which the `Algol` language requires). If you load the latter explicitly in your preamble, with

```
\lstloadaspects{keywordcomments}
```

the error that's bothering you doesn't occur. You can use that as a workaround until the maintainer of `listings` fixes the bug.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstloadaspects{keywordcomments}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=ALGOL,morekeywords={ID}]
... some code ...
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```